# AngularJS MetisMenu doesn't collapse the first time the page loads or after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating web admin website, I'm using AngularJS, Bootstrap-3 and the Metis Menu plugin of jQuery.

I downloaded an open source bootstrap admin template, the template it's very simple, so I started adapting it so it could work like and single page AngularJS website.

At first, the `MetisMenu` wasn't collapsing when I started to add `ng-include` directives to reduce the HTML code, I used and `ng-include` directive to include the sidebar menu part, and the footer and header parts, So I put this line in all of my controllers `$('#side-menu').metisMenu();` and it worked, but it doesn't work the first time I access the page or if I reload the page using F5.

Example:

If I go to `http://localhost/frontend/pages/index.html` the `MetisMenu`  doesn't show with the menu items or tabs collapsed and if I press the collapse icon it doesn't collapse the tabs it doesn't work in general.

But if while I'm on that page I click a menu tab this tab takes me to `http://localhost/frontend/pages/index.html#/dashboard` and the `MetisMenu` works, the `MetisMenu` shows all the tabs collapsed and the tabs collapse icon works. I can go to all the pages in the menu and all the pages work fine. But if I refresh the page by pressing F5 the `MetisMenu` stops working, so I need to select again a menu option that would take me to `http://localhost/frontend/pages/index.html#/forms` or `http://localhost/frontend/pages/index.html#/anything` so the `MetisMenu` could work again.

I believe that when I access a "#/any page fragment" the `MetisMenu` works because angular ngRoute call the controller and inside the controller I have this line `$('#side-menu').metisMenu();` that makes the `MetisMenu` works, but when I go back to the index.html is the browser that's taking me there without the ngRoute, the same happens when I refresh or reload the page the `$('#side-menu').metisMenu();` isn't getting called

The only pages that I have it's my index.html and inside this page, I have a directive `ng-view` that shows the fragments of different pages when I call then like this "#/my fragment" because I'm trying to do a single page application

Here are my routes, I'm using `ngRoute` to route my pages

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/forms', {
        templateUrl: '../angular/templates/userTemplates/createUser.html',
        controller: 'UsersCtrl'
    }).
    when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: '../angular/templates/dashboardTemplates/dashboardTemplate.html',
        controller: 'DashBoardCtrl'
    }).
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../angular/templates/dashboardTemplates/dashboardTemplate.html',
        controller: 'DashBoardCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

Here is my angular Controller

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
}]);

angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('DashBoardCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
}]);
```

here is my jQuery file

```
$(function() {

$('#side-menu').metisMenu();

});

//Loads the correct sidebar on window load,
//collapses the sidebar on window resize.
// Sets the min-height of #page-wrapper to window size
$(function() {
    $(window).bind("load resize", function() {
        topOffset = 50;
        width = (this.window.innerWidth > 0) ? this.window.innerWidth : this.screen.width;
        if (width < 768) {
            $('div.navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse');
            topOffset = 100; // 2-row-menu
        } else {
            $('div.navbar-collapse').removeClass('collapse');
        }

        height = ((this.window.innerHeight > 0) ? this.window.innerHeight : this.screen.height) - 1;
        height = height - topOffset;
        if (height < 1) height = 1;
        if (height > topOffset) {
            $("#page-wrapper").css("min-height", (height) + "px");
        }
    });

    var url = window.location;
    var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
    }).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
    if (element.is('li')) {
        element.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

and here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- ANGULAR -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular/controllers/user/userController.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular/controllers/dashboard/dashboardController.js"></script>

    <script src="../angular/routes.js"></script>
    <title>SB Admin 2 - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body ng-cloak>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0" ng-include="'../angular/templates/masterPageSecctions/navigationTemplate.html'">
        </nav>  <!-- here is where I include html code with a directive ng-include-->


        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and here is the fragment that contains the metis menu

```
<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
    <li class="sidebar-search">
        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#dashboard"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#forms"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please add this to codepen or plunker